# TSQL - How to Update a column in a table with iteration

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, iteration, relational-database

I have 2 tables, Tasks and Staff.  These are within a relational database.

[image: Before table update]  [image]

And what I would like to do is update the StaffID column in Tasks table with 4 staffIDs (1,2,3,4) and do it in iteration so the end result will be:

[image: After table update]

So that way StaffID '1' will have tasks 1, 5, 9 and so on, as well as all the other staffID's doing the same thing.  So far, my query looks like this, but I'm sure I'm missing a lot of things:

```
update Tasks
set StaffID = 2
where
```

And that's what I have, I'm stumped as to what I need to do after that.  Any help with this or links to documentation that show how to do this would be great.

Comment: What is the relation between staff id and the tasks assigned to it,  is there another table defining this relation?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: UdayrajDeshmukh and Fact, I've update the question with what I believe will answer your questions

Comment: You can achieve by using mod e.g SELECT *,MOD(taskid,4) FROM tasks. then use it in the update query with case e.g case when mod(taskid,4)=1 then 'X' when mod(taskid,4)=2 then 'Y' etc

Answer (score 0):

```
create table task as
WITH tasks as 
(select 1 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 1' title,getdate()-1 createdDate union all
select 2 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 2' title,getdate()-2 createdDate union all
select 3 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 3' title,getdate()-3 createdDate union all
select 4 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 4' title,getdate()-4 createdDate union all
select 5 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 5' title,getdate()-5 createdDate union all
select 6 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 6' title,getdate()-6 createdDate union all
select 7 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 7' title,getdate()-7 createdDate union all
select 8 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 8' title,getdate()-8 createdDate union all
select 9 taskid,1 staffid, 'Task 9' title,getdate()-9 createdDate 
)
SELECT * FROM tasks

update task
set staffid =  case when mod(taskid,4) =1 then 1
                 when mod(taskid,4) =2 then 2
                 WHEN mod(taskid,4) =3 then 3
                 WHEN mod(taskid,4) =0 then 4
            end from task b
where taskid=b.taskid;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message ' 'MOD' is not a recognized built-in function name.'  I forgot to mention that I'm doing this with TSQL.

Comment: @Tscott . . . Use the `%` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the taskid has no gaps, then arithmetic on it will solve your problem.  Otherwise, you can use `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by t.taskid) as seqnum
      from tasks t
     )
update toupdate
    set staffid = ((seqnum - 1) % 4) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to assign the staff to the tasks, please read the comments to adapt your needs (if needed).

```
DECLARE @AmountStaffToAssign INT = 4

;WITH SequentialStaffIDs AS
(
    -- Get a sequential ID asigned to each of your StaffID (if not already sequential)
    SELECT TOP (@AmountStaffToAssign)
        S.StaffID,
        SequentialID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
        Staff AS S
    -- You can filter your staff to reassign here and also order them
),
SequentialTaskIDs AS
(
    -- Get a sequential ID asigned to each of your TaskID (if not already sequential)
    SELECT
        S.TaskID,
        SequentialID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
        Task AS S
    -- You can filter you tasks to be assigned here
),
TaskReassignment AS
(
    SELECT
        T.TaskID,
        T.SequentialID,
        StaffSequentialID = ((T.SequentialID - 1) % @AmountStaffToAssign) + 1
    FROM
        SequentialTaskIDs AS T
)
UPDATE T SET
    StaffID = S.StaffID
FROM
    Task AS T
    INNER JOIN TaskReassignment AS R ON T.TaskID = R.TaskID
    INNER JOIN SequentialStaffIDs AS S ON R.StaffSequentialID = S.SequentialID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answers: https://sqleditor.net/q/rk6YcdEtM

```
UPDATE T SET StaffID = S.StaffID
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TaskID) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Staff) AS seq, StaffID FROM Tasks
 ) T
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StaffID) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Staff) AS seq, StaffID FROM Staff
) S ON T.seq = S.seq;
GO
```

You can try more detail here: https://sqleditor.net/q/rk6YcdEtM